# Is there a function to print the String of an object in an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

So I am doing OOP, and I have a Zoo. My zoo is a class which holds Zookeepers and Animals. The animals have the attributes "name, fed, feeder" (str, bool, obj). On my Zoo terminal a zookeeper can use my program. He can: Feed an animal, check if one animal is fed and can also list all animals. This is where my problem occurs. (Note that all my animals are in the same class for now and are named "Lars the Icebear" or "Nemo the clownfisch"

When I am checking for one animal, I enter the Animals name and call my select_animal method. This returns the instance of this animal if it is found or 'none' if it is not found. elif 'c' because a and b are feed animal and list all animals. check_animal checks if it has been fed.

```
elif(chosen_program == "c"):
    selected_animal = select_animal()
    checked_animal = first_zoo.check_aniaml(selected_animal)
    if(checked_animal == True):
        print(str(selected_animal.name) + " has been fed by " + str(selected_animal.keeper.name))
    else:
        print(selected_animal.name + " hasn't been fed yet!")
```

This works fine. It prints nicely "Simba the lion hasn't been fed yet" or "Simba the lion has been fed by Mike"

When I print the list though:

```
elif(chosen_program == "b"):
    print("\nKeepers:")
    for Keeper in first_zoo.keeper_list:
        print(Keeper.name + ", ", end='')
        print(Keeper.fed_animals)                   # fed animals is a list
    print("\nAnimals:")                               
    for Animal in first_zoo.animal_list:            #
        print(Animal.name + ", ", end='')           #
        print(str(Animal.fed) + ", ", end='')       #bool
        print(Animal.feeder)                        #pointer to the feeder, not a str!
```

This works too, but not like I want it to. if I put print(Animal.feeder) it prints "Lars the Icebear, True, "

I just want to print the name, so I tried what I did in c) with print(Animal.feeder.name)

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'name'
  File "C:\Users\x\Google Drive\Files\Programs\python\Library\main.py", line 122, in <module>
    print(Animal.feeder.name)
```

Summed up: this is my question. How do I print the name of the keeper. Is there a nice function in python where I could xprint(animal_list) and it would give me ("Lars the Icebear", True, "Mike"; "Nemo the clownfisch", False, none) etc ?

Comment: Are Zookeepers and Animals classes?

Comment: @doctorlove correct.

Comment: I think you need to show your class definitions if you want help writing string methods for them

Answer (score 0):

**First Thing** 
Animal.feeder is of type string i.e. str, so you cann't access attribute 'name' which is not present at all.

**second thing**
I don't know what is type of 'animal_list'

suppose if it is a *object of class zoo* then you have to write method `__str__(self)` in the class like that

```
class zoo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
       '''create str here and return'''
       temp = ""
       for Animal in first_zoo.animal_list:            #
           temp += Animal.name + " "str(Animal.fed)+" "+Animal.feeder+"\n"
       return temp
```

if animal_list is list then you can print it by `print(animal_list)`

Comment: Animal.feeder is an object, its the instance of the feeder.

Comment: What sort of object? Another class? If so, give that a `__str__` method too

Comment: So I havev the class keeper and the class animal. the class feeder has only a name. When the feeder feeds the animal, the instance of the keeper is stored in animal.feeder.

Answer (score 0):

To control what gets printed for a class, you can implement the magic `__str__` method, to do as you please.
This is:
"Called by the str() built-in function and by the print statement to compute the “informal” string representation of an object."

Add a method that returns the string you want inside your class, like this:

```
def __str__(self):
  return "Hi"
```

(You want to dig into your object to find the actual string you want to return)

Comment: Thing is, my object [Mike, 19, other attributes] is saved in animal.feeder. In the option c) it has no problem doing  str(selected_book.borrower.name), but in b) Book.borrower.name does not work for some weird reason.